# dynamic column data, client side sorting and server pagination in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying this for the first time to load dynamic column data and column name from server, and also to use server side pagination.

The issue is when i use datatype : 'local' in jqgrid AJAX call(second one), the data is displayed and server-side pagination is disabled. But when I use datatype : 'json' in AJAX call, no data is displayed.

Please help me to get a simple, clear solution to achieve dynamic column binding, client-side sorting and server side pagination.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                                type : "POST",
                                url : contextPath + "/getEntities",
                                dataType : "json",
                                success : function(result) {
                                    var colD = result.response,
                                    colM = result.colModList,
                                    colN = result.colNames;

                                    $("#list").jqGrid({
                                        url : contextPath + "/getEntities",
                                        datatype : 'json',
                                        mtype : 'POST',

                                        data : colD,
                                        colNames : colN,
                                        colModel : colM,
                                        pager : '#pager',
                                        rowNum : 10,
                                        rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
                                        sortname : 'column1',
                                        sortorder : 'asc',
                                        viewrecords : true,
                                        gridview : true,
                                        caption : 'My first grid',
                                    });

                                },
                                loadComplete : function() {
                                    $("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'});
                                },

                                error : function(x, e) {
                                    alert(x.readyState + " " + x.status
                                            + " " + e.msg);
                                }
                            });
                });
```

There is no issue with the JSON data received from the server as i am able to see the data when datatype : 'local' is set(in the second AJAX call). It would be a great help if anyone provides a working example.

Another question is in my mind, why to reload the grid and how to do that. Where to put the reloading code. I am not getting this part.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Answer posted.
Works perfect for implementing dynamic columns with server side pagination.

Comment: I'm confused why you would ever use `datatype: local` in your setup?

Comment: @Mark i don't want to use local as I want to use server side pagination to load data. just for testing I used local and saw that the data is displayed in the grid.

Comment: Ok great, so lets completely ignore localdata now, if you do so, what doesn't work?

Comment: @Mark if I use localdata, the code above works and data is displayed in the grid, else no data is displayed in the grid.

Comment: Yea, but there is NO reason you should have to use localdata to accomplish what you are trying to do, so I think you need to remove it from the equation otherwise it's a red herring.  So now the question is why isn't your data showing.  When you initialize the jqGrid, does your grid go out and post and retrieve the json Data? You might have to settle for doing two ajax calls to build the grid and not pass the data down as part of the initialization.

Comment: yes json data is retrieved from the server. only problem is with the displaying part.

Comment: Yes, but my point is, first ajax call: setup and initialize jqGrid. Then jqGrid goes out to your server and gets data and displays it, it should be as simple as that.

Comment: this is what i have done here, or trying to do here. thinking where lies the issue in the above code.

Comment: Remove `data : colD,` as it has no place in a jqgrid that is going and getting it's own data from a server.

Comment: then from where i will I get the data?

Comment: The ajax call that the jqGrid will make when initialized. If it isn't requesting data you can trigger it manually.

Comment: @PravatPanda: If you use `datatype : 'json'` then `url` will be used to fill data and `data` parameter will be ignored. If you need to use `data` parameter you have to use `datatype: "local"`. In the case `url` parameter will be ignored. Another remark to your code: you use `loadComplete` as parameter of `$.ajax` which is wrong. `loadComplete` is parameter (callback function) of jqGrid instead. The current code of `loadComplete` will do nothing.

Comment: @Oleg Hello Oleg, I was just waiting for your comments/answers.

Comment: @Oleg Changed the code as per your advice. Got it working fine. Good part of you is that you jump directly into concepts which helps a lot.Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Working Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : contextPath + "/getEntities",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(result) {
            var colM = result.colModList,
            colN = result.colNames;

            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url : contextPath + "/getEntities",
                datatype : 'json',
                mtype : 'GET',
                jsonReader : {
                    root : "response",
                    page : "page",
                    total : "total",
                    records : "records",
                    repeatitems : false,
                    id : "column1"
                },
                colNames : colN,
                colModel : colM,
                pager : '#pager',
                rowNum : 10,
                rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
                sortname : 'column1',
                sortorder : 'asc',
                viewrecords : true,
                gridview : true,
                caption : 'My first grid',
            });

        },
        error : function(x, e) {
            alert(x.readyState + " " + x.status
                    + " " + e.msg);
        }
    });
});
```